# How to fetch outlook calendar available time using python O365 library for schedule an appointment using aws lex -aws lambda function?

Tags: python, outlook, aws-lambda, office365, aws-lex

I'm a beginner to AWS and AZure. I'm doing a lex bot which will do a appointment based on the agent's outlook calendar.I head to fetch outlook calendar details (available time for appointment) and make an appointment on outlook calendar using python library **O365**. I'm having the client ID and secret key and an api to fetch the O365 calendar(Got it from the admin). I don't have a proper documentation about this O365 functionalities or methods.

```
from O365 import Account
credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')
account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

When i ran this code, says me something like visit some URL and paste the API endpoint.

**Questions:**
1)I need to know the request type and format to call this api and calendar related functions in the O365(or a proper documentation to use this O365)
2)Will this O365 library can be imported inside the aws Lambda ? will it be pre-installed?

**UPDATE:**
I got tenant id and after using the own user identification method, now I'm able to authenticate. But After that when I'm  doing this

```
from O365 import Account
import datetime as dt
credentials = ('xxxxx-0d57-49e5-xxxx-xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxx^[xxxxxxx[%')


account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='xxxxxx-e1ec-xxxxxxx-b1d9-xxxxxxxxx')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')

schedule = account.schedule()

schedule.get_availability(['test@angkorwat.onmicrosoft.com'],dt.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 19, 45),dt.datetime(2019, 9, 10))
```

I'm getting the following error  **Resource not found for the segment 'calendar'**,

```
> C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop>python user_himself.py 
> Authenticated! Client
> Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
> https://graph.microsoft.com /v1.0/calendar/getSchedule | Error
> Message: Resource not found for the segment ' calendar'. Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "user_himself.py", line 13, in
> <module>
>     schedule.get_availability(['test@angkorwat.onmicrosoft.com'],dt.datetime(
> 2019, 9, 5, 19, 45),dt.datetime(2019, 9, 10))   File
> "C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
> \O365\calendar.py", line 1931, in get_availability
>     response = self.con.post(url, data=data)   File "C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
> \O365\connection.py", line 725, in post
>     return self.oauth_request(url, 'post', data=data, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
> \O365\connection.py", line 703, in oauth_request
>     return self._internal_request(self.session, url, method, **kwargs)   File
> "C:\Users\Mypc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
> \O365\connection.py", line 665, in _internal_request
>     raise HTTPError('{} | Error Message: {}'.format(e.args[0], error_message), r esponse=response) from None
> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/calendar/getSchedule | Error
> Message: Resource not found for the segment 'calendar'.
```